# What causes a puff of white smoke every time starting a cold lawnmower?

Tags: small-engine, smoke, lawnmower

I have a new lawnmower that seems to make a puff of white smoke every time I start a cold engine. It doesn't make any smoke when starting a warm engine or during operation of a warm engine, and has no problems when operating it. It's an auto-choke model.

When I ordered the lawnmower from mail order, it arrived full of oil (apparently the seller considered it better to ship an oiled machine rather than risk a clueless buyer starting the engine without oil) and was probably in every possible orientation during transportation so it's possible small amounts of oil are in places where no oil should be. At least the oil amount in the crankcase was about correct so I suspect the oil lost to places where no oil should be is at most dozen milliliters or so.

What is the cause of this puff of white smoke?

At first, I thought it was a one-time event caused by oil in the intake burning (due to shipping an oiled lawnmower). However, the smoke seemed more white rather than blue. Also the first time I started the cold mower the puff was maybe bit larger, but second and third use (on different days) starting the cold mower also made a similar puff of smoke, maybe bit smaller these times. It would seem incredible to me that incorrect orientation in shipping an oiled lawnmower would cause a puff of some even on the third use. Or could this smoke be the result of oil burning small amounts at a time?

Is the puff of smoke excess fuel that the auto-choke system too generously provides to the engine, that vaporizes due to combustion and subsequently condenses again into smoke after travelling through the cold muffler cooling the exhaust gases?

Or is the puff of smoke water that has condensed inside the engine during storage that vaporizes during combustion and after encountering the cold muffler, condenses again?

Or is the puff of smoke caused by water produced when combusting the fuel, that is initially vapor, and then after the cold muffler condenses into small liquid droplets (smoke)?

Comment: I wouldn't know for sure, but would assume this is fuel related and probably connected directly with the auto-choke. It could be leaking down into the combustion chamber (or into the intake tract) from the carb and then upon cold startup is enough to be too rich and cause the condition you're suggesting. I doubt it would be water as there's just about no way for enough water to get trapped to cause this condition while sitting. Oil would be as you stated, with a blue puff instead of white. You may want to contact the manufacturer and see what they have to say, or do a model search for problems

Comment: The last paragraph could be the reason. On a cold day a car puts out visible steam until the exhaust has warmed up. Then it still puts out water vapour (a product of combustion) but the gases are hot enough that it doesn't condense into steam (not smoke).